# Double Count if statement on excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having trouble creating a countif statement. Here is an example of what I want to do.

[image]

I need the statement to check if two of the criterion are true. Ex. Count the number of circuits that are 1'' Al.

I have over a 1000 data points that i have to do this for. 
Ive tried sumif nested inside of a countif but i just cant seem to make it work.

Any Advice?

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS` for multiple criteria.

Comment: I don't think i explained my problem very well.  i need to sum the number of circuits for each group. this is what i tried so far. What do i need to change?
 =COUNTIFS(Table1[Size ''''],"=1",Table1[Type],"=Al")

Comment: It sounds like you need to use `SUMIFS` then.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can use `SUMIFS` to solve your problem.

Let's say that 'Size ""' is column A, 'Type' is column B and 'Number of circuits' is column C.

The formula would be:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,1,B:B,"Al")
```